# Table Row Border - Migradoc

Tags: c#, pdfsharp, migradoc

I am creating one table with migradoc. I need to give row border but not in each cells. So i need only outer border.

**Code:**

```
        Row row = source.AddRow();
        row.Borders.Width = 0.2;
        row.Borders.Color = Colors.Black;
```

Here is my existing code. With this i got border for all cells. Please help to avoid border in each cells

Answer (score 2):

you can set width for specific border like

```
yourrow.yourcell[0].Borders.Left.Width = 1.5;
```

following above example you can set width for required border separately but if you want to set width for all four border at once you use table.SetEdge method like
// Set the borders of the specified cell range

```
 table.SetEdge(5, this.table.Rows.Count - 4, 1, 4, Edge.Box, BorderStyle.Single, 0.75);
```

for more information have a look on [MigraDoc example](http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/Invoice-sample.ashx)

Answer (score 1):

You can set each border (left, right, top, bottom) for each cell independently.

You can use the `SetEdge` method of the `Table` class to make things easier.

See also (search for `SetEdge`):
http://pdfsharp.net/wiki/HelloMigraDoc-sample.ashx